# Gmail Opens Last Read Email

Tags: gmail

I've noticed an occasional problem using Gmail on my Pixel 2XL running Android 10.  At times, when I open the app, it immediately opens the last email I viewed.  The only work around I've found is to close the app and restart it.  I've seen a similar reported problem, but, it was for IOS.

I'm using a [Spectrum email](https://smtpimap.email/android/spectrum.net-email-setup.html) account with with a "mobile.charter.net".  I looked at the settings, but, there was nothing that appeared to be a problem.

Can anyone shed some light on this problem?

Comment: Gmail remains in it's last state unless you close it or it gets killed unless RAM is needed for another app. Hence one could say that the main reason for this behavior is that your device has a lot of RAM...

Comment: Using Nexus 5 on Android 7.1 (LineageOS 14.1), Gmail always opens the main page (list of email) provided that I close the app using the back button. However, if it's only "paused" (by pressing the home button or switching to other apps), then Gmail (and most Android apps) will reopen the last state.

Comment: Thanks for the replies.